# What is the difference between the two entanglement circuits?

Tags: qiskit, entanglement, quantum-circuit

For a three qubits system to be in an entanglement(GHZ) state, the circuit can be built as per Qiskit,

[image: GHZ state way 1]

Here, the control bit of the second X gate is on q0. what if the control bit is shifted to q1. This also leads to entanglement. what is the difference between the two different ways?

Further to my question, I did the same for 5 qubits, I get different results:
[image: image1_samecontrol_bit]
[image: image_different_control_bits]

which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two circuits are **equivalent**.

```
import qiskit.quantum_info as qi
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc1.h(0)
qc1.cx(0,1)
qc1.cx(0,2)
op1 = qi.Operator(qc1)
print(qc1)
     ┌───┐          
q_0: ┤ H ├──■────■──
     └───┘┌─┴─┐  │  
q_1: ─────┤ X ├──┼──
          └───┘┌─┴─┐
q_2: ──────────┤ X ├
               └───┘


qc2 = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc2.h(0)
qc2.cx(0,1)
qc2.cx(1,2)
op2 = qi.Operator(qc1)
print(qc2)

     ┌───┐          
q_0: ┤ H ├──■───────
     └───┘┌─┴─┐     
q_1: ─────┤ X ├──■──
          └───┘┌─┴─┐
q_2: ──────────┤ X ├
               └───┘


print(op1 == op2)
True
```

---

To see this more explicitly, note the following idenity

[image]

Thus you have

[image]

Note that $CNOT*CNOT = I$, and when the control qubit is $|0\rangle$ nothing happened so you can remove it.

Comment: I am reading all your answers to gain more insights and here you are! answering my question. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem! :) I hope they are helpful.

Comment: I tried 5 qubits entanglement and I used these two differing ways(above two) and I see that I see that the results are totally different. AM I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should be the same. You might have created the circuit wrong. But they should be the same to any number of qubits.

Comment: I have the two circuits as a follow-up question. COuld you look at it. Thank you.